# Elementor - Add Buy now button dynamically next to add to cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, dynamic, elementor

I am attempting to add a buy now button in **elementor** on custom single product page so there are two buttons:

add to cart
buy now (which will redirect to checkout & skip cart)
I still want add to cart to function as usual.

How can I achieve this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After a little research I came up with a solution to this problem

using PHP code snippet

```
<?php

  
   $product = wc_get_product();
   $id = $product->get_id();
    echo home_url('/checkout/?add-to-cart='.$product->id);
    
?>
```

then i linked the button to this code using shortcode